# Vue.JS Changing parent tag depending on condition

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

I want to have the same childrens but change the parent tag depending on the condition

currently I am using

```
draggable(v-if="dragMode" v-model...)
  .dragable1
  .dragable2
  .dragable3

notDraggable(v-else v-model...)
  .dragable1
  .dragable2
  .dragable3
```

but I would love to have something like this(selecting only 1 arrow as the parent).

```
draggable(v-if="dragMode"...) <----------
.notDraggable(v-else)         <----------
   .dragable1
   .dragable2
   .dragable3-
```

My current solution "flickers" when I change the value of dragMode :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried dynamic components? `<component :is="draggableOrNonDraggable" v-model="model">` depends on condition you can set `draggableOrNonDraggable` property with your component name.

Comment: hi, I will try and let you know. thank you so much for replying